# Second display not detected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics, external-monitor

I'm connecting with a HDMI cable. It was working, but for some reason stopped working, here is what I did until now?

- Restart the computer and connect again;
- Go to configurations and check if the display shows up, it's not there;
- Restart the monitor.
- Tried another monitor with another cable, the same behavior happens.
- Tried the other OS I have in the same notebook, the same behavior happens.
- Checked the same table and monitor with another notebook, it worked.

My configurations:

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Graphics Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)

Kernel info:

> Linux insp-7560 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

There are some errors in the output of `dmesg` are:

```
[  270.143265] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  274.629530] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  452.691211] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e4
[  452.691221] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e4(Transmitter ID)
[  452.691228] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  452.691232] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[  641.941847] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e4
[  641.941865] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e4(Transmitter ID)
[  641.941875] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  641.941883] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[  696.176349] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e4
[  696.176367] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e4(Transmitter ID)
[  696.176378] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  696.176386] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[  700.334881] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  716.100019] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1104.383811] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e4
[ 1104.383822] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e4(Transmitter ID)
[ 1104.383828] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 1104.383832] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[ 1126.232837] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e4
[ 1126.232861] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e4(Transmitter ID)
[ 1126.232884] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[ 1126.232896] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[ 1501.322758] dell_wmi: Unknown WMI event type 0x12
```

The output of `xrandr` is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Hmm, the `xrandr` output shows it doesn't see the screen at all. Are you sure the cable is OK? Can you connect it to another computer? Do you have another operating system installed to test with? If you do, can you boot into it and see if the screen is recognized there?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I added the tests you said to the question now. With other notebook it works, but with the same in another OS it doesn't, maybe some hardware issue?

Comment: firstly make sure you have 4.15 kernel. this issue may a PCIe lower state, try to disable your pcie on the grub add `pci = noaer` into `/etc/default/grub` file and reboot.

Comment: If you see the same issue in different operating systems, then it is almost certainly a hardware problem, yes. Unless you have 2 graphics cards and one is disabled in the BIOS/EFI, I don't see any other answer. So if you only have one card, and two different operating systems fail to detect a monitor that works with another machine, then it sounds like a hardware issue.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I added the kernel version to the question, I have the mentioned version. I'm gonna try what you said.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri by adding the `pci = noaer` fixed the issue!!! thank you!

Comment: @ThomasWard I believe because the option was set in the grub it has consequences on both OS systems, what do you think?

Comment: and what about you @terdon ?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri first of all, great catch! Second, could you please expand that into an answer and post it so the question can be marked as answered? If you could also explain how this could be affecting different operating systems, that would be great!

Comment: The Bus has fail if a bad choose of Hardware managements. More description would be appreciated :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As mentioned at the comments.

The error output said :

```
[  452.691211] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e4
[  452.691221] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=00e4(Transmitter ID)
[  452.691228] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[  452.691232] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout
```

Probably you have a issue about PCIe Lower State. you need to disable this feature at GRUB.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
```

saved your `/etc/default/grub` and `sudo update-grub`, finaly rebooy your system.

Hope this helps.